# Можно ли "сдавать испытание" или только "проходить испытание"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, словосочетания

Можно ли употреблять сочетание "Сдавать испытание", "Сдавать вступительные испытания" или только "проходить"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В словаре Ушакова:
[испытание](https://slovar.cc/rus/ushakov/403951.html)
2. Проверочный опрос, экзамен (офиц.). *Приемные испытания в учебное заведение.*

В словаре Ефремовой:
**сдавать**, несов. перех. и неперех.
8) *перен.* перех. Проходить проверку на умение, знание чего-либо.

Если испытание приравнено к экзамену, то почему бы его не сдать?

*Поступающие **сдают вступительные и аттестационные испытания** на русском языке* (А. Гусев. Права студента (юридический справочник учащихся)); *Отдельные категории поступающих на базе среднего общего образования могут **сдавать общеобразовательные вступительные испытания**...* (из правил приема в Политех); *Теперь ему только через год, экстерном и платно, можно будет попытаться **сдать испытания** по-новому* (И. Валериев. Ермак. Начало).